# Performance impact of calling lots of functions in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have lots of sub routines and functions like these:

```
Sub LogInfo(Txt)
    'Write an entry to the log file

    If LogEnableInfo Then Log "Info: " & Txt
End Sub
```

Or this:

```
Function GetSettingValue(Key)
    'Get the value of a setting or an empty string if the setting is not set

    Dim Res

    If Settings.Exists(UCase(Key)) Then Res = Settings(UCase(Key)) Else Res = ""

    GetSettingValue = Res
End Function
```

Or this:

```
Sub DoExp(Exp, ErrTag)
    'Execute an HS.Exp with Error handling and Debugging

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next

    HS.Exp Exp

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        LogError "HS.Exp """ & Exp & """ , Tag: " & ErrTag
        Err.Clear
    ElseIf LogEnablePut Then
        Log "Put: HS.Exp """ & Exp & """ , Tag: " & ErrTag
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

They're really one liners that don't do much, but I use lots of times, so I don't want to type it out every time. I also use recursive functions a lot.

Since speed and memory use is critical to my application, what I would like to know is if the act of calling a function or sub in `vbscript` has a considerable performance impact? I know that in PHP, this has been cited as a performance issue. Can I just go ahead and create zillions of little nested functions to do everything or should I use them a little more sparingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The rule "violate good practice (don't repeat yourself, clean program structure, ...) for speed gains!" is bad.
- I doubt that there is even one real life VBScript program that becomes fast enough as soon as you inline functions/subs/methods - if you show me two, I'm willing to discuss using/writing a preprocessor for VBScript that expands macros and adds line numbering to scripts.
- If speed is important, you should benchmark early/continously and optimize for speed by choosing better algorithms or better tools (COM, Net, Shell).
- If (3) does not help, switch to a better language.

**Samples to illustrate what I mean by "better tools" (#3):**

- using one ADO connection (created once (with late binding in VBScript)) to execute many SQL statements on a folder of .CSVs instead of using a FSO, .Readline loops, Splits, and complex IFs
- using one .Net component (ArrayList, StringBuilder, ...) for many operations instead of using ReDim Preserve on native arrays or string concatenation in a loop
- shelling out to `dir /s /b c:\where\ever\*.vbs` instead of a (faulty/inefficient) homegrown/stolen recursive directory walker that looks at all files to filter the .vbs

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I agree with points 1, 2 & 3. Point 4 is not an option for what I'm working on. I'm wondering at what level of granularity of functions do they stop being good programming practice though?

Comment: There should be little overhead in calling a VBScript Sub or Function. I disagree with #3, if he's speaking about calling COM from VBScript anyway. Since VBScript doesn't support early binding, making a number of late-bound COM calls that require VTable lookups through IDispatch interfaces is the surest way to cause slowdowns. That includes the "made-for-VBScript" libraries like Shell, Network, and FileSystemObject.

Profile sections of your code to find the true bottlenecks. Shaving 1/2 sec off a sub that's used once is fine. But shaving 100ms off a sub that's called 1000s of times is better.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience using functions repeatedly is a bad thing in VBS, in a small test script I wrote I found that using functions were about 5 times slower.

```
startTime = Timer
x = 0
For i = 0 To 1000000000
    x = x + 1

Next

endTime = Timer

WScript.Echo x
WScript.Echo CStr(endTime - startTime)

startTime = Timer

y = 0

For i = 0 To 1000000000
    y = fooBooGoo(y)

Next

endTime = Timer

WScript.Echo y
WScript.Echo CStr(endTime - startTime)


Function fooBooGoo(p)
    g = p + 1

    fooBooGoo = g
End Function
```

The output I got was:

```
1000000001
306.6289
1000000001
1554.875
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are used to carry on a specific task or to perform specific operation. Same as in other languages, but in OOP they are usually called "methods", at least when they are attached to a class. It means to be able to work. Function is the process where a machine can work and make things efficient. here's an ex. that is used in a sentence. the machine won't work right. Or what you could say is the function is the ability to work so the mathematical definition would be the ability to solve an equation/problem. Function means working.

So, with regard to using function re-cursive's would be better but overall in object based languages like vbscript, objects should be created and set=nothing later for actually making system consume memory efficiently.

Thanks